# How to be able to move data out of scope using default move constructor?

Tags: c++, move, forwarding

I want to move data into other scope. And it seems to work... yet destructor of an object [seems to crush application with runtime exception:](http://ideone.com/AdE5hx)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct A {
    void * data;
    A() {
        data = new char[10000];
        std::cout << "A()" << std::endl;
    }

    ~A() {
        if(data != nullptr) {
            delete [] ((char *)data);
            std::cout << "Deleted Data!" << std::endl;
        }
        std::cout << "~A() " << std::endl;
    }
};

void aDo2(A && a) {
    cout << "Do2" << endl;
}

void aDo(A && a) {
    cout << "Do" << endl;
    aDo2(A(a));
}



int main() {
    {
        A a;
       {
           aDo(move(a));
       }

        cout << "why" << endl;
    }
    cout << "here?" << endl;
    // your code goes here
    return 0;
}
```

How to make move into other scope to work correctly?

Comment: Did you try adding a proper move constructor? Or simply use std::string?

Comment: The `delete` expression in the destructor is wrong.

Comment: And if you have a fixed size, why not use `std::array`?

Comment: Rvalue references (like `A&&`) do not move objects. They are just references. If you want to move objects, you need to pass by value (where the argument is an rvalue expression). And to do that, you'll need a move constructor to be implemented.

Comment: Why default one results in application crush?

Comment: Are you asking about moving data and rvalue references, or about the crash in the destructor?

Comment: crash in the destructor

Answer (score 0):

When you allocate memory with the `new[]` operator you must free it with the `delete[]` operator, otherwise you will get undefined behavior (which is one of the most common reason behind crashes).

Also, when you move a pointer, you should clear the old pointer as it's not done automatically and can leave you with two (or more) objects with the sae pointer.